# Running of gauge couplings in the Standard Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization

I'm sure many of us are familiar with the following plot showing the running of the inverse of the fine-structure constants of the SM.

[image: running of SM couplings] 
(I got the picture from google)

At one-loop, the expressions for the fine-structure constants of the hypercharge, weak, and color gauge groups are,

$$\frac{1}{\alpha_1 (\mu)} \approx 59 - \frac{41}{20 \pi}\log[\frac{\mu}{M_Z}]$$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha_2 (\mu)} \approx 30 + \frac{19}{12 \pi}\log[\frac{\mu}{M_Z}],$$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha_3 (\mu)} \approx 8.5 + \frac{7}{2 \pi}\log[\frac{\mu}{M_Z}],$$

where the numerical values of $\alpha$'s in the first terms in RHS are at the mass of the Z boson $M_Z$. Now, if I plot these (from $\mu=100$ GeV to $\mu=2\times 10^16$ GeV) using Mathematica, I get this:

[image]

The slopes of the $log$'s in the previous equations do not produce the shape appearing in the first plot.

What am I missing here? How is the first plot, which we usually see in the literature, produced?

**Update**: What I was missing is skills with Mathematica :p, Now I get the correct plot:
[image]

Comment: Your plot doesn't pass a sniff test:  The equation for the running of $\alpha_3$ is a line with a slope of roughly 1 and a $y$-intercept of 8.5.  It should rise to about 25 by $\mu = 10^{16} M_Z$.   Perhaps you're taking log twice?

Comment: Yes you are right, I took it twice like any stupid would do.. I suspected I did something wrong in my plotting. Now I get the desired plot when I use the LogLogPlot function. Previously I used Plot, with the interval being from Log[MZ] to Log[10^16] so the log was taken twice.

Comment: Or even better is the LogLinearPlot function which plots log scale on the x-axis only.

Comment: You have to take care of the difference between $log_{10}$ units and $ln$ units. Your formulae are expressed in $ln$ units, but the graph uses $log_{10}$ units. Why $\alpha_3$ is not a straight line ? See [test plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+59+-+%282.3%29%2841%2F%2820+Pi+%29%29+%28x-2%29%2C+30+%2B%282.3%29%2819%2F%2812+pi%29%29%28x-2%29%2C+8.5%2B%282.3%29%287%2F%282+Pi%29%29%28x-2%29%2Cx%3D0%2C%2B19)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a software tool.

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic". But it's still amusing. :-)

Comment: I agree, and I don't think it will be helpful to anyone except me since I made a mistake and realized it has nothing to do with physics. ;-p